# Function not returning a boolean

Tags: jquery

The isUpdatable method returns undefined when it should be returning true or false. 
Is this a scope issue. When I do a log on the isUpdatable method I see it outputting true and false but the keyup function is returning undefined.

```
$( function() {
var updatableEl = ['home', 'block', 'cat'];

inputFields.keyup(function(){
      var $input =  $(this);
      console.log("isUpdatable= ", isUpdatable( $input ));
    });

    function isUpdatable( el ){
        $.each( updatableEl, function( intIndex, objValue ){
           //console.log(" objValue = ", el.hasClass(objValue));
           return el.hasClass(objValue);
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.each` returns the original jQuery object (for chaining).
It ignores the return value of its callback.

Your code doesn't make sense anyway.
You're computing three different booleans; which of those three do you want to return?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for anyone who might have had a similar problem.

```
function isUpdatable( el ){            
    for( var i=0; i< updatableEl.length; i++){
                if(el.hasClass(updatableEl[i])){
                    return true;
                }
            }
    }
```